# How to Install Angular theme in existing app?

Tags: angularjs, themes, dashboard

I recently bought an Angular admin dashboard theme
(http://flatfull.com/themes/angular/angular/#/app/dashboard-v1) and I'm interested in using it in an existing angular app. This seemed straightforward till I realized that the angular theme is an independently operable app with its own bower,package,grunt files. I guess one way to integrate the theme is to copy the html/cs/jss files into the existing app manually, but is there a better way to do so? Like installing it via bower or something?